# Approximately how long after forming a critical mass of fissionable material does it explode?

Tags: critical-phenomena

Just making up some quantities of variables to reduce the “depends” answers/comments.

Given, say:

- enriched uranium
- mass of 1.5 x critical mass
- spherical shape
- brought together “quickly” (a few milliseconds)

Is there any data on how long after this state is achieved that rapid runaway fission takes place?

An estimate of the order of magnitude would be good enough. What would the duration be measured in of these options?

- microseconds
- milliseconds
- seconds
- minutes

Comment: Neutrons are introduced by irradiating beryllium with an alpha emitter. Otherwise, the fission would depend on [spontaneous fission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_fission#Spontaneous_fission_rates) or background muons releasing neutrons.

Comment: I suppose this a a question about fast-neutron bombs and not about the fizzling "explosions" with thermal neutrons that may occur in criticality accidents.

Comment: A few shakes of a lamb's tail (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shake_(unit)).

Comment: FWIW, a subcritical mass can also achieve supercriticality via the use of a neutron reflector. This has happened by accident a few times, eg in the notorious [demon core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_core) incidents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time required for neutron multiplication to develop into an explosion is of order ~microseconds. By that time, the neutron multiplication process has gone through about 80 "generations".